# Whats the best way to handle Nav item selection?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React + Redux for one of my applications. Where I want to have a Nav, with 2 Nav Items. I want to handle the change of Nav item based on the user action.

I'm planning to use my redux store to have a state for this to handle this change. Is this a good approach or please guide me for a better solution. I'm a beginner in this.

My Nav will look something like this

```
<Nav {...props} activeKey={active} onSelect={onSelect} style={styles} appearance="subtle" justified>
    <Nav.Item eventKey="nav-1">
        Nav 1
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item eventKey="nav-2" >
        Nav 2
    </Nav.Item>
</Nav>
```

(using rsuite js for this)

My initial state of the store will be something like this

```
const initialState = {
    selectedNav: 'nav-1'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes I think you are on the right way, but Nav 1 and Nav 2 does not have to know about the state the parent Component does

- pass the redux state as props to the parent Nav and then render the selected Nav from the element props.

```js
<Nav  onSelect={onSelect} style={styles} appearance="subtle" justified>
    {props.selectedNav === 'nav-1' && (
        <Nav.Item eventKey="nav-1">
            Nav 1
        </Nav.Item>
    )}
    {props.selectedNav === 'nav-2' && (
        <Nav.Item eventKey="nav-2" >
          Nav 2
        </Nav.Item>
    )}
</Nav>
```

and make a global action for the user interaction to change the active nave.

> Note:
>   you can take another approach for more cleaner code by wrapping the Nav 1 and Nav 2 into a switch component and render the active one.